# IE/Edge JavaScript is not executed properly when read from cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a weird issue with IE and Edge. When I first load a page everything works fine. However when I navigate away from the page by going to a new page on the *same* website, JavaScript on the new page will show errors. If I now go back to the previous page, it, too will no longer work properly and dev. console will show errors.

If I leave dev. console open while navigating and attempt to set breakpoints where the console mentioned errors occur, they are not triggered.

If I refresh the page (with or without dev. tools open) everything works as expected.

In Chrome and FireFox everything just works.

Here's the page in question:
[image: link to problem page]

(Sorry according to guidelines I was forced to submit it as a picture, and I was not allowed to submit a direct link)

The first time you load it, everything should be fine. However, when you say click on "Products" the "Products" page will load with JS errors, and if you go back, the original page will no longer work.

From my attempts to solve the issue it seems that it has to do with the fact that IE no longer executes scripts in the proper order once they are cached. However why it always works in other browsers then?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer I was hoping for, but I found a workaround (though the original IE/Edge behavior remains unexplained).

Basically I was dynamically loading scripts like so:

```
    function bmpl_loadScript(scriptName, callback, async, crossorigin, integrity, defer) {
        if (!bmpl_arr[scriptName]) {
            bmpl_arr[scriptName] = true;
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = scriptName;
            if (async) { script.async = 1; }
            if (defer) { script.defer = 1; }
            if (integrity) { script.integrity = integrity; }
            if (crossorigin) { script.crossOrigin = crossorigin; }
            if (callback) { script.onload = callback; }
            body.appendChild(script);
        }
    }

    //Load scripts
    //bootstrap depends on jquery, and scripts depends on both, hence they are not async and are nested
    bmpl_loadScript('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js', function () {
        bmpl_loadScript('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', function () {
            bmpl_loadScript('/v3/js/scripts.min.js', function () {
                //Do final JS loading here
            }, false,false,false,true);
        }, false, 'anonymous', 'sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS',true);
    },false,false,false,true);
```

So, apparently, unlike Chrome and FireFox, IE/Edge cannot figure out how to run the same routine properly if scripts are already in cache. Therefore I had to go back to the original:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/v3/js/jquery.fallback.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script>bmpl_window_onload();</script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>jQuery.fn.tooltip || document.write('<script src="/v3/js/bootstrap.fallback.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="/v3/js/scripts.min.js"></script>
```

This has the added benefit that it allows for fallbacks in case loading from CDN fails.

The reason why I wanted to go with the dynamic loading approach was that Google's Page Speed Insights tool complained about render-blocking JS. However I suppose first priority should be that a site works, and then how fast it loads, considering that the difference between load speeds would probably be minimal.

I still hope someone might shed a light on this IE/Edge behavior, so I am not marking this as an answer.